# Isolation level of out-of-transaction select

Tags: database, relational-database

Will out-of-transaction SELECT see only committed data?

**UPD.** My database is MySQL

**UPD.** I'm interested in simple SELECT statement which comes without explicit transaction. What data will it see? How can I change it?

Comment: It depends on what the statement, session or database isolation level set (or defaulted) to.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your questions without more details. Is it a *Yes/No* question? (the answer to that would be no, for example in Sql Server you can run a `SELECT WITH(NOLOCK)`. Is your question regarding the default behavior? Please provide more details. Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are asking regarding InnoDB, since MyISAM does not support transactions.

There is no such thing as *out of transaction*, even with the default `autocommit=1`, every statement for itself is a transaction.

The answer to your question depends on what you mean by `only committed data`.

Say we have a table with a row:

```
INSERT table (id, Counter, LastUpdates) VALUES (8, 100, '2011-03-08 22:04:00');
```

While session A is modifying the row:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE table SET Count = 101, LastUpdates = NOW() WHERE id = 8;
SLEEP(100);
COMMIT;
```

If session B issues a select before session A commits the transaction, what will happen is dependent on the transaction *isolation level* of session B.

- `READ UNCOMMITTED`: session B will read the **newly modified** row (counter = 101).
- `READ COMMITTED` / `REPEATABLE READ (default)`: Session B will see the **latest committed row** (counter = 100).
- `SERIALIZABLE`: session B will block until session A commits.

Here is how a one can change the session transaction level without *declaring* a transaction.

```
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

Comment: READ UNCOMMITTED will actually return the dirty row (counter=101) even before it's committed, that's why it's called "read uncommitted"
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_dirty_read

Comment: @CharonME You are correct. I have updated the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Specific database in mind, we could probably tell you what the default is from a vanilla installation. Otherwise ... it's whatever the person who configured and installed the database system set it to, or what someone set it to after that.